# missingRef in ajv JSON validator for nested schema

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, ajv

I've got a schema that, simplified, looks like this:

```
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
"$id": "https://example.com/schemata/my.schema.json#",
"type": "boolean",
"default": true,
"$defs": {
    "oid": {
        "title": "Object ID",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "oid_list": {
        "title": "Object Ids List",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {"$ref": "#/$defs/oid"},
        "uniqueItems": true
    }
}
}
```

And I'm trying to use it with Ajv to validate some JSON data.

```
const Ajv = require ('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv();
const fs = require ('fs');
const schema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./schemata/my.schema.json'));
const validate = ajv.compile(schema.$defs.oid_list);
const data = ['wibble', 'wobble'];
const valid = validate (data);
```

The code above gives me a `"missingRef": "#$defs/oid"` error.

But the schema validator in vscode has no problem resolving the references and applying schema validation to the files I've told it to look at.

I'm a newbie with Ajv. Hopefully it's a simple error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's a lot of `const`s. Do you write all your code like that?

Comment: it's a bit cargo cultish - I started with the example here https://ajv.js.org/guide/getting-started.html However, if a quantity isn't meant to change by design, yes I always declare them `const`.

Answer (score 1):

I made some progress. This code works as expected:

```
ajv.addSchema(schema.$defs.oid, '#/$defs/oid');
ajv.addSchema(schema.$defs.oid_list, '#/$defs/oid_list');
const data = ['wibble', 'wobble'];
const valid = ajv.validate (schema.$defs.oid_list,data); // == true
```